# django form field validation using parameter from URL

Tags: django, validation

I have a visit-create class based on a [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView).  It accesses the organization from the URL, so it's passed in as a keyword arg.

```
class VisitCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOrgRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = models.Visit
    form_class = VisitCreateForm
    # template_name is "visit_form.html" from CreateView

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # get the patient for this visit
        patient = models.Patient.get_by_pk(self.kwargs['patientId'])
        if not patient or patient.organization.name != self.kwargs['orgStr']:
            raise SuspiciousOperation('Patient does not exist')
```

I want to write a form field validator that checks something about the visit, but it needs the orgStr.  Here is the current form field validator, but it can't get the orgStr:

```
class VisitCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Visit
        ...
    # Allow only one visit per day
    def clean_visit_date(self):
        visit_date = self.cleaned_data['visit_date']
        if models.Visit.get_visits(visit_date, visit_date, self.kwargs['orgStr']):
            raise ValidationError('There is already a visit on this date')
```

How do I mark a field error on visit_date?  Either I have to pass orgStr to the form somehow, or mark the field error in VisitCreate.form_valid.

Please don't suggest adding the orgStr as a hidden field in the form.  That seems crazy.

Comment: I would try to keep the validation in the form. You can add errors in the `form_valid()` method with `form.add_error(...)`, but then you need to handle your invalid form (e.g. by returning `self.form_invalid(...)`), which complicates the flow of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the view's `get_form_kwargs` method to pass `orgStr` from the URL:

```
class VisitCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOrgRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(VisitCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['orgStr'] = self.kwargs['orgStr']
        return kwargs
```

You then need to override the form's `__init__` method to handle `orgStr`.

```
class VisitCreateForm(ModelForm):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.orgStr = kwargs.pop('orgStr')
        super(VisitCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # You can now access `self.orgStr` in the `clean_visit_date` method.
    def clean_visit_date(self):
        visit_date = self.cleaned_data['visit_date']
        if models.Visit.get_visits(visit_date, visit_date, self.orgStr):
            raise ValidationError('There is already a visit on this date')
```

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar.  If only I could give you more than one upvote.